# drawing line graph with primary and secondary y axis c#

Tags: c#, mschart, excel-interop

I have been researching ways of drawing charts in c#. I have a specific requirement of drawing a chart with a y axis and x axis and a seconday y axis.I have tried using excel Interop but have not found a solution.I have started working on MSChart component but not reached anything yet the data i am working with is

```
index lines branches
1      20     5
2      30     8
3      34     6
```

i want to plot the indexies on the x-axis and scale for lines on the left y axis and a scale for branches on the right y axis.

I am using .net versions 2.0 and 3.5 if that helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When creating a series, set the `YAxisType` property to `AxisType.Primary` or `AxisType.Secondary`

```
        var lines = new Series("lines");
        lines.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        lines.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 20));
        lines.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 30));
        lines.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 34));
        lines.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        chart1.Series.Add(lines);

        var branches = new Series("branches");
        branches.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        branches.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 5));
        branches.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 6));
        branches.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 8));
        branches.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
        chart1.Series.Add(branches);
```

This results in a chart like this, which sounds like what you are after.  The example below is a bit ugly, it has lines for primary and secondary y-values, etc. but you can clean that up the way you want it by setting the properties of the chart control.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are the properties you set to align them?

Comment: As @muzzlator asks, what property will make the Y Primary and Secondary Axis line up there gridlines?